# how to update a slider based on other two slider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, slider

I have two input slider and i want third slider to be a product of first two slider and also the third slider must dynamically change its value on changing the values of first two slider.

Can you please help me with it.

Here is what i tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="value1" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" />
    <input ng-model="value2" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" />
    <input ng-model="value3" ng-value="value1 * value2" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" />

  </body>

</html>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.value1=0.2;
  $scope.value2=0.1;
  $scope.value3=0;
});
```

Plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/tfPH0I24LBWlBUf1YlnH?p=preview) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-change to make a function call on elements that will have its value evaluated. [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Here is the code snippet

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="value1" ng-change="changed()" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" />
    <input ng-model="value2" ng-change="changed()" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" />
    <input ng-model="value3" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" />
</body>
```

app.js

```
  $scope.changed = function(){
    $scope.value3=$scope.value1*$scope.value2;
  }
```

Comment: I can understand what you are trying to achieve through ng-value, but ng-value does not evaluate model's values, therefore it will not update the slider